# Regex: I can't create a Regex for matching Keywords?

Tags: java, regex

I am kinda new to regex, I created Regex for matching Number,Operation and Identifier, but I couldn't manage how to recognize the next token is a language Keyword for example like:

`int or double or public .....`.

Here is my code :

```
enum TokenType{
NUMBER("-?[0-9]+.[0-9]+|-?[0-9]+"),      //int and double
OPERATION("[*|/|+|-]"),                 // arithmetic operations  
WHITESPACE("[ \t\f\r\n]+"),            // white space
IDENTI("[_]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*[[_]*[A-Za-z0-9]*]*"),// string like _string_string_..
//......
```

The problem here is every keyword like `int` will be an identifier, for example if we have

`public static int NUMBER_OF_STUDENT;`

> Output:
>
> > public  IDENTI 
> >     static  IDENTI 
> >     int     IDENTI 
> >     NUM...  IDENTI 
> >     ........

How to create another regex to match some keywords like `int, double, ....`?

---

If needed I will post the whole code of this program.

Comment: Well, I guess you just have to match the keywords before matching identifiers. Everything that remains is an identifier. The regexp itself should be as simple as
`\b(int|double|boolean|...)\b`

Comment: @JohannesH. : I tried this, but it's not working too.

Comment: Your `OPERATION("[*|/|+|-]")` should probably be `OPERATION("[*/+-]")`

Comment: @Pshemo: em, interesting, don't need the `|` operator between them, I interested to ask why?

Comment: Because [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) like `[abc]` means `(a|b|c)`. If you put `|` inside you will just make your class also accept `|` literal. Also notice that `-` is normally used to create range like `a-z` and it is treated as literal only because you placed it at the end of character class. Normally you would need to escape it with \.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern should be:

```
"(int|double|public|...and so on)"
```

nothing fancy

Comment: Yes, only a simple thing like this drive me crazy. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?!int)(?!double)([a-z0-9]+)
```

will match ntblah and itblah and dblah but not intblah and doubleblah

the (?!int) says dont match anything that begins with int.
This becomes the regex for your identifier just use that syntax to exclude all of your keywords.

Comment: and I need that in which part of the regexs ?

Comment: this is in addition to Artur 's answer @Caffè what are you using this for?